# Thread communication through IPC

Tags: firefox-os, b2g

The scenario is how InputReaderThread communicates to b2g(main) thread.

Is XPCOM needed in this scenario? Be more specific, will these threads communicate to each other through pipe? shared memory or socket?

I dont find any document discusses this topic yet, please let me know if there is any available on the site.

Comment: What is your goal? Are you trying to communicate from one FirefoxOS app to another?

Comment: when I dug into how FxOS handles touch input event, this part confuses me. That's why I asked this question here.

Comment: hey Aras, any comment?